# How to avoid duplicate reducer in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

1. I have avoided duplicate code for registerSuccess and loginSuccess, registerFailure and loginFailure.
2. and I need different types respectively

````
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.isLoading = false;
        },
        loginFailure: (state, action) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.token = null;
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.error = action.error;
        },
        registerSuccess: (state, action) => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.isLoading = false;
        },
        registerFailure: (state, action) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.token = null;
            state.user = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.error = action.error;
        }
    }
});```
````

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/429 it looks like they don't have specific support for it, but you can split the reducer to different function that you can call.